# external interrupt using microphone sensor Arduino UNO

Tags: c#, arduino-uno

Hello when i am not using my Arduino i want it to go to sleep so i can save battery power. this is my output right now
**i am going to to wake up
i am going to to wake up
i am going to sleep**

when it goes to sleep it doesn't wake up again when i clap.

I am using arduino uno and this sensor https://www.auselectronicsdirect.com.au/audio-microphone-module-for-arduino-projects?gclid=CjwKCAjwhMmEBhBwEiwAXwFoEVAz-xxw7jaHoXDWixiTV1IHz8TF5i4tKr_1jjTK8s3JvowUDUDnCBoCxdgQAvD_BwE

here is my code

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#define interruptPin 2


Servo myservo;
int pos = 0;
int soundSensor = 2;

boolean LEDStatus = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  myservo.attach(7);

  pinMode(soundSensor, INPUT);

}
void Goint_to_Sleep() {
 Serial.println(" i am going to sleep");
 delay(5000);
  sleep_enable();
   attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), wakeUp, LOW);
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
  sleep_cpu();

}

void wakeUp() {

  sleep_disable();
  detachInterrupt(0);

}
void loop() {
  
  int SensorData = digitalRead(soundSensor);

 
  if (SensorData == 1) {
    wakeUp();
     Serial.println(" i am going to to wake up");
    if (LEDStatus == false) {

      LEDStatus = true;

      for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 40) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees

        // in steps of 1 degree

        myservo.write(pos);

        delay(15); // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position

      }

    } else {

      LEDStatus = false;

      for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 20) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees

        myservo.write(pos);
        delay(15); // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
 Goint_to_Sleep();
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads-up. You are declaring pin 2 twice, first as `interruptPin`, then as `soundSensor`. This might be prone to confusion and misfiring of the ISR

Inside your interrupt function, you should wrap your logic inside `cli();` and `sei();` to avoid false triggering during the interruption. Do not use `detachInterrupt()`.

Review the documentation from `avr/sleep.h` ([here](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__sleep.html)). As it reads, you MUST make sure that interrupts are enabled before sending the CPU to sleep. I believe you are missing a sei() before sending the CPU to sleep

I would advise you to use an external (strong) pull-up to guarantee that pin 2 won't be triggered unless is via the sensor.

Finally, please observe that according to your logic, the interrupt service will be called any time the pin goes LOW. This will override the `else` from the conditional inside the `loop()` (at least this will occur after the first time you call the (*mispelled*) function `Goint_to_sleep()`).

Think of another approach to accomplish what you want. Just be careful with the ISRs that you implement

EDIT:  I forgot to mention something extremely important:

You need to be absolutely sure that the output signal from the microphone that you are connecting to is above the threshold for a digital signal (~2.60-2.8V). Having said that, are you sure that the interrupt edge detection should be LOW when clapping? I think it must be high in which case the pin should be pulled low. You can always reverse this logic and amplify the signal with an external transistor to convert the sensor's signal into an adequate digital pulse